# Objectively good answers should not be downvoted

Tags: feature-request

Twice now answers that I have offered and that I know have helped users have been downvoted. I know this to be true because one answer I gave has been seen 11,000 times on YouTube and has helped other users tremendously in their work.  I find this terribly unjustified. If Stack Overflow looks to offer answers that are worthwhile to the community it needs to change its norms to accept these answers, indifferent to whether some high-level user thinks they are out of place or not.

Stack Overflow should offer a way to counter these downvotes which are unjustified. Does this exist?

Comment: Yeah.. I stopped at ' I know 100% are good'.  The thing is, on SO, your opinion does not matter much when it comes to votes.

Comment: The worst possible judge of the quality of a post is the poster.  You are getting feedback from your peers.  If you disrespect the judgement of your peers then you are using the completely wrong website.  It is supposed to be fun, if it is not then just don't.

Comment: See: [I've just been downvoted. How should I react?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react)

Comment: ' indifferent to whether some high-level user thinks they are out of place or not' sounds perilously close to the all-too-common 'hostile, elitist 10K+ mob, downvoting without reading the question because they think they're better than the rest of us', deluded, paranoid twaddle.

Comment: Yet... The YouTube users express otherwise. I am not trying to gain points here but help other users, but I am beginning to get the feeling that is not a mutually shared goal here. My point here was NOT to seem like a know-it-all, because I have just started to program, but rather to make the point that if an answer has helped, why downvote it? Either way, I will edit my question given that it seems to have offended.

Comment: Unless you've deleted some, none of your answers have down votes.

Comment: @JasonJurotich - I'm not offended, (yet:).  I also have not inflicted the meta-effect on your questions.  I have no Google API knowledge, so I don't feel like I shoud participate, though the first question I saw looked very much like a works request and/or gimme teh codez.. :(

Comment: If this is indeed about your question rather than your answers, you may well have fallen into the common trap for self-answered questions. Your answer may be great, but your question is lacking. Always make sure to write both as if they don't come from one and the same author. A great answer doesn't justify a poor question.

Comment: @BSMP Some of their questions were downvoted, just not negative-scoring.

Comment: "I am not trying to gain points here but help other users." Then it shouldn't matter if a few people downvote. It doesn't stop you providing answers (unless you get downvoted a lot), and people can still see it. If you don't care about points, and genuinely believe your answers are helpful, then why waste time worrying about a few downvotes?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - I just wanted to point that out because the OP is arguing that the content of his answers is useful but that's not really relevant because that's not what's been down voted. (I saw that they had two negative scored questions when I wrote my answer)

Comment: I am now beginning to understand the problem. And for that reason, will again edit my question. The problem was I did NOT receive precise feedback. In the past, I have edited both my questions and my answers when I was told to, precisely because I am not trying win an argument or be a know-it-all. If the person who downvoted my questions had just left a comment on bettering my question, I would have done just that, but it was lacking, which has caused all this conversation....

Comment: @JasonJurotich People are not obliged to give reasons for downvotes. Get over them.

Comment: @JasonJurotich Looking at your posts, you seem to have some confusion about how Stack Overflow works. Every one of your questions asks for a "script" to do something; most of them actually say "script to" as part of the title. Most of them simply state that you need a *complete script* to accomplish some task. Such questions are too broad and usually off-topic as requests for recommendations of off-site resources. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to Answer questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yep, I am beginning to see that. Won't be making that mistake again. Just wish there was a website that had this type of community and were open to helping to offer script, then I would happily move the questions there so as not to have brought the ire of the community upon me here.

Comment: so... "my questions are good, I get no feedback"... did you read the help center? Did you look around meta a bit? EVERYTHING is there to explain to you what you should/shouldn't ask about. Why is it the job of high-rep users (few and far between) to educate you if you can't educate yourself when the data is there?

Comment: @Patrice as was mentioned here in the comments, what I found out was that my answers were fine, but the way I was wording my questions was wrong, mainly because they were too open. I understand that now, but that was not clear to me at the beginning. If, when I entered Stack Overflow about a year ago that was clarified to me, I most likely would not have posted this question, but I was getting upvotes from what I was posting and that only added to the confusion. I will be much more careful of what I post in the future.

Comment: and my question is why do WE have to explain it to you? I'm saying if you take the time to look it up, you will understand how the site works. You don't have to beg for feedback. Do your research and you'll be able to abide by the rules. Can't help but notice you don't even have the "informed" badge. So even after ALL this, you haven't taken the tour in the help center. LOOK UP THAT DATA and don't expect everyone to read it for you and rephrase it :).

Comment: I don't know... SE has become so complex, I don't necessarily hold it against people anymore when they do something intuitive that turns out to be against our rules. (Still, I have to downvote on principle for complaining about a very small number of downvotes and requesting a major change to the system because of them  :)

Comment: haha, I don't know how to raise the white flag here, but I think my error has been clearly reprimanded and I promise to avoid it in the future. Now if some merciful moderator would kindly close this question (given that it was marked as duplicate) I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Stack Overflow should offer a way to counter these downvotes which are
>   unjustified. Does this exist?

If you're asking if there's a way for you, personally, to undo the votes of other users, then no. If your content is of high quality and useful to other users, then you'll get more up votes than down votes.

That's for the general question.

However, *Objectively good answers should not be down voted*, does not apply to your situation because no one down voted your answers, they down voted your **questions**.

Even when you self-answer your questions, they need to be asked in a way that allows others to actually answer them. The quality guidelines still apply.

Comment: I understand. You are correct. I need feedback to see why the question was downvoted. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The only justification that is ever needed is that a user finds your answer "not useful". Be it because it's insufficient, incorrect or has other problems. Nothing will ever interfere with that, unless they target you and not your content.

So no, there is no mechanism to counter downvotes which you find unjustified. All you can do is figure out whether or not there is a justification you may have missed, or in case there isn't, swallow the downvote and realize that good answers over time will get their deserved upvotes.

Comment: Thanks Bart, I have now realized that it was because of not getting precise feedback that I began this. I will ask the user to offer more precise feedback instead of just downvoting without telling me why.

Comment: @JasonJurotich don't do that; whoever voted will likely never see the comment and you can assume that if they'd wanted to leave one they would have.